# Updating Row in Slick 3.0.0-RC3, using

Tags: scala, slick

This is how I update a row of table using Slick 2.1,

```
private def updateEntity(id: Long, row: TTable#TableElementType) = {
        db.withSession { implicit session =>
          val result = query.filter(_.id === id).update(row)             
          result.toLong
        }
      }
```

After I upgrade to Reactive Slick,  `db.withSession` showing deprecation warning as withSession deprecated. what is the
Action-based api syntax for updating a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slick 3.0 uses pure functional, monadic I/O without side effects. In Action based API, you will have to use `db.run` which will take the `Query` and return a `Future`.

So in your case, it will be

```
private def updateEntity(id: Long, row: TTable#TableElementType): Future[Long] = {
    db.run(query.filter(_.id === id).update(row)).map(_.toLong)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @mohit it Shows could not find implicit parameter session, one more help, how to write insert method that returns last inserted record...

Comment: There is no difference between the way to write the queries in Slick 3.0 and Slick 2.1. The only difference is that instead of getting the result directly, you will get the result in a Future and instead of db.withSession ..... you will use db.run. So to get the last inserted record, the example is given in http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0-RC3/queries.html#inserting

Comment: Yeah I have to `import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._`, I have an extended driver, that is causing the problem, now I resolved it. Thank you.

Comment: is there any way to do an insertOrUpdate by row?